# How to use classes with Android Studio?

Tags: java, android-studio, signal-strength

I would like to know how to use classes such as [SignalStrength](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SignalStrength.html) in Android Studio.

Looking at the documentation it seems like I need to import `android.telephony.SignalStrength`
So from my (basic) understanding of Java, in order to access `getLevel()` I would need to do something like this:

```
SignalStrength signalStrength = new SignalStrength();
int level = signalStrength.getLevel();
```

But I'm getting an error indicating that `SignalStrength` is not public and can not be accessed from outside its package.

So how can I access these imported classes?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to get the signal strength? This class is not used like that. Because you just `new` an instance, all the information is initial status.

This is another example to get GSM signal strength:

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
CellInfoGsm cellinfogsm = (CellInfoGsm)telephonyManager.getAllCellInfo().get(0);
CellSignalStrengthGsm cellSignalStrengthGsm = cellinfogsm.getCellSignalStrength();
cellSignalStrengthGsm.getDbm();
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply. Unfortunately it crashes the app with the following error: `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0`

Comment: Have you add the permission to access the telephonyManager? <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/> or see the example to use telephonyManager http://www.javatpoint.com/android-telephony-manager-tutorial

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply. Unfortunately even after adding the permission I still get the same results.